# Need to ignore last two values in a lists column using Hive HQL

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I have a column which contains all the values in lists.

```
Column A|Column B
AAA     |1 2 45 67 89
BBB     |16 25 36 45 89 63
CCC     |52 63 98 41 22 66
```

Here in the above table, column B contains string values which are actually lists.

I need to ignore the first two and the last two values in Column B.

I tried using split function where i can ignore first two values. But ignoring last two values is the challenge as I have different sized lists.

The code which I used is:

```
select distinct column_A,column_B,split(column_B,'\\s')[2] AS ign_first_val,
            split(column_B,'\\s')[-2] as ign_last_val
FROM Xyz
```

Is there any easy way to ignore first two and last two values in a list using HQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `regexp_extract`:

```
select regexp_extract(column_B, '^\\s*(\\d+\\s+){2}(.*?)(\\s+\\d+){2}\\s*$', 2)
```

The first part of the regex skips the first two values, and the last part skips the last two values, leaving just the middle part to be extracted into group 2 which is what is returned by the expression.

Here's a demo of the regex working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/laeQFS/1)